# install phonegap with npm giving error as behind proxy

Tags: node.js, networking, cordova, proxy

here is my npm debug log

error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
 error network and is related to network connectivity.
 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
 error network
 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 error command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
 error cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
 error node -v v0.10.29
 error npm -v 1.4.14
 error code ECONNRESET
 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

if anybody know the solution please help,thanks

Comment: Is your computer network using any proxy

Comment: @ManjeshV Thank you friend for your reply,I tried so many solutions and finally done with installation.

Comment: So write the solution below. so anyone get the same error then it helps